# Implement Z-Wave AES 128 OFB in C#?

Tags: c#, aes, z-wave

I'm trying to implement AES 128 OFB encryption / decryption to match the Z-Wave Application Security Layer (S0) implementation. I can test the correct behavior by using a PC Controller application, with the following test data:

```
External Nonce: C7 16 D1 58 7E D2 9F 18
Internal Nonce: 68 DE E6 4A 88 A4 A3 E8
Security Key: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Decrypted Message: 00 98 06 2D C3 51 38 5D D8 4D 25 F5 ED 3B C5 B5 AA E2 36
Encrypted Message: 50 AE 49 A7 88 6C A9 BF E6 DA 36 A0 EF B8 CF D2 AA E2 C1
```

[image: Facit from Silicon Labs Z-Wave PC Controller]

Information I have:

- AES-128 OFB. Output Feedback, or OFB, is the mode of operation used to encrypt and decrypt
  the payload.
- IV = (sender's nonce || receiver's nonce) (the payload is encrypted with
  the external and internal nonce concatenated together.)

This is my attempt to implement the Z-Wave AES 128 OFB encryption / decryption in C#:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace AesEncryption
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] externalNonce = new byte[] { 0xC7, 0x16, 0xD1, 0x58, 0x7E, 0xD2, 0x9F, 0x18 };
            byte[] internalNonce = new byte[] { 0x68, 0xDE, 0xE6, 0x4A, 0x88, 0xA4, 0xA3, 0xE8 };
            byte[] securityKey = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            byte[] unencryptedMessage = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x98, 0x06, 0x2D, 0xC3, 0x51, 0x38, 0x5D, 0xD8, 0x4D, 0x25, 0xF5, 0xED, 0x3B, 0xC5, 0xB5, 0xAA, 0xE2, 0x36 };
            byte[] initializationVector = InitializationVector(externalNonce, internalNonce);

            var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/OFB/NoPadding");
            var keyParameter = new KeyParameter(securityKey);
            ICipherParameters cipherParameters = new ParametersWithIV(keyParameter, initializationVector);
            cipher.Init(true, cipherParameters);
            var encryptedMessage = cipher.DoFinal(unencryptedMessage);
            var encryptedMessageAsHexString = ToHexString(encryptedMessage); 
        }

        static byte[] InitializationVector(byte[] externalNonce, byte[] internalNonce)
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[externalNonce.Length + internalNonce.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < externalNonce.Length; i++)
                iv[i] = externalNonce[i];

            for (int i=0; i< internalNonce.Length; i++)
                iv[i + externalNonce.Length] = internalNonce[i];

            return iv;
        }

        public static string ToHexString(byte[] buffer)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(64);
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append($"{buffer[i]:x2}");
                if (i < (buffer.Length - 1))
                    stringBuilder.Append(' ');
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that my code produces this encrypted result:

```
"6c 60 2b 6f 53 bb 36 74 3f 1a 50 dc fe db dd c7 d4 84 aa"
```

while the correct result is:

```
"50 AE 49 A7 88 6C A9 BF E6 DA 36 A0 EF B8 CF D2 AA E2 C1"
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: Here is a [similar thread](https://community.silabs.com/s/question/0D51M00007xeQ8XSAU/s0-encryption-type?language=en_US) (but without a solution). With your data, I wonder about the Zero key.

Comment: Zero key is just as good as any other key. In practice one would use a different key.

Comment: The implementation is correct ([here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fc3G92)) and the ciphertext can be verified independently ([here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'00000000000000000000000000000000'%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':'C716D1587ED29F1868DEE64A88A4A3E8'%7D,'OFB','Hex','Hex',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)&input=MDA5ODA2MkRDMzUxMzg1REQ4NEQyNUY1RUQzQkM1QjVBQUUyMzY)). I.e. either the data is wrong (hence the question about the key) or your information about the processing of the data (IV derivation, algorithm, etc.) is incomplete or wrong.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks a lot for test testing! Looks like the Silicon Labs Z-Wave PC Controller must be doing some additional tricks.

Comment: @Topaco I got some more information related to the Security Key. It actually goes through an additional step to generate the actual encryption key. The step is documented as KE = AES(KN*V2).  V2 is defined as 0xAA repeated 16 times. But I tried to run this through en AES mode ECB and then feed the resulting encryption key to the next step (AES OFB), but the result did still not match.

Comment: To get the expected ciphertext, furthermore, the two nonces must be concatenated in reverse order, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the additional information that the *actual* encryption key is derived from an encryption of the key material

```
0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

with the AES primitive and the posted key

```
0x00000000000000000000000000000000
```

the expected ciphertext can be reproduced by using as IV the concatenation of internal and external nonce instead of the concatenation of external and internal nonce.

Full code:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System;

namespace AesEncryption
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] externalNonce = Hex.Decode("C716D1587ED29F18");
            byte[] internalNonce = Hex.Decode("68DEE64A88A4A3E8");
            byte[] securityKey = Hex.Decode("00000000000000000000000000000000");
            byte[] unencryptedMessage = Hex.Decode("0098062DC351385DD84D25F5ED3BC5B5AAE236");
            byte[] initializationVector = InitializationVector(internalNonce, externalNonce); // Fix 1: IV = internalNonce||externalNonce

            // Derive key
            byte[] keyMaterial = Hex.Decode("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"); 
            byte[] encryptionKey = encrypt("AES/ECB/NoPadding", securityKey, null, keyMaterial); // Fix 2: derive encryption key

            //  Actual encryption
            byte[] encryptedMessage = encrypt("AES/OFB/NoPadding", encryptionKey, initializationVector, unencryptedMessage);
            var encryptedMessageAsHexString = Hex.ToHexString(encryptedMessage);
            Console.WriteLine(encryptedMessageAsHexString); // 50ae49a7886ca9bfe6da36a0efb8cfd2aae2c1
        }

        static byte[] encrypt(string algorithm, byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] plaintext)
        {
            var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher(algorithm);
            var keyParameter = new KeyParameter(key);
            ICipherParameters cipherParameters = iv != null ? new ParametersWithIV(keyParameter, iv) : keyParameter;
            cipher.Init(true, cipherParameters);
            return cipher.DoFinal(plaintext);
        }

        static byte[] InitializationVector(byte[] nonce1, byte[] nonce2)
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[nonce1.Length + nonce2.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(nonce1, 0, iv, 0, nonce1.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(nonce2, 0, iv, nonce1.Length, nonce2.Length);
            return iv;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the required ciphertext:

```
0x50ae49a7886ca9bfe6da36a0efb8cfd2aae2c1
```